# Creating an object array in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

i am struggeling to create an object array from two input-groups,
each group has 3 inputs with data-side = left/right
each input has class "elm" and data-pos = a/b/c

```
<input class="elm-left elm" name="l1" data-pos="a" data-side="left"/>
<input class="elm-left elm" name="l2" data-pos="b" data-side="left"/>
<input class="elm-left elm" name="l3" data-pos="c" data-side="left"/>

<input class="elm-right elm" name="r1" data-pos="a" data-side="right"/>
<input class="elm-right elm" name="r2" data-pos="b" data-side="right"/>
<input class="elm-right elm" name="r3" data-pos="c" data-side="right"/>
```

desired output is:

```
[
 {
  "name":"title1",
  "data":[
   {
    "left" :{"A":10,"B":10,"C":10},
    "right":{"A":20,"B":20,"C":20}
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

my output is:

```
...,"data":[
 {
  "left":{"A":20,"B":20,"C":20},
  "right":{"A":20,"B":20,"C":20}
 }
]
```

```
var sides = {};
var info  = {};
$(".elm").each(function () {

  var pos   = $(this).data('pos').toUpperCase(); //a,b,c
  var side  = $(this).data('side'); //left, right
  var val   = $(this).val();

  info[[pos]] = val;

  sides[side] = info;
});

data.push(sides);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML too. Regardless, it looks like you only have one `info` set for both sides, with values inserted to it regardless of their "side". In addition, you are assigining `sides[side] = info` but `info` is an object so it is not cloned. At the end of the execution, `sides['left']` and `sides['right']` both refer to the exact same object.

Comment: `info[side] = { [pos] : val }` with `data.push(info);` looks better but leads to `"data":[{"left":{"H":"10"},"right":{"H":"20"}}]`

Comment: `info[side] = ` overwrites existing values, you need `info[side][pos] =` after initializing both side objects. I don't know where the "H" came from, if you are trying a new approach then add it fully inside the question.

Comment: if i replace `info[side]` with `info[side][pos]` an error is thrown:  `info[side] is undefined`

Comment: You need to initialise a new object for info[side] before you can use info[side][pos]: 
 `info[side] = info[side] || {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise a new object for `info[side]` before you can use `info[side][pos]`

```
info[side] = info[side] || {}
```

this is a common pattern to either use the existing value if there is one or create a new one object if needed.

You can then use this object directly without the need for the `info` variable which was getting re-used for different sets of values.

```js
var sides = {};

$(".elm").each(function () {

  var pos   = $(this).data('pos').toUpperCase(); //a,b,c
  var side  = $(this).data('side'); //left, right
  var val   = $(this).val();

  sides[side] = sides[side] || {};
  sides[side][pos] = val;
});

var output = { name: "title1", data: [] };
output.data.push(sides);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="elm-left elm" name="l1" data-pos="a" data-side="left" value="20"/>
<input class="elm-left elm" name="l2" data-pos="b" data-side="left" value="20"/>
<input class="elm-left elm" name="l3" data-pos="c" data-side="left" value="20"/>

<input class="elm-right elm" name="r1" data-pos="a" data-side="right" value="20"/>
<input class="elm-right elm" name="r2" data-pos="b" data-side="right" value="20"/>
<input class="elm-right elm" name="r3" data-pos="c" data-side="right" value="20"/>
```

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm. I have never seen `sides[side] = sides[side] || {};` and without your help i would have never solved it this way. Thanks a lot for your help! Also thanks to Noam for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: To explain the meaning of `sides[side] = sides[side] || {};`: The '||' operator is logical OR, so its checks the value of `sides[side]`. If it's already an initilaized object then that's the value assigned back to `sides[side]` so it just remains the same object. If it's undefined, then the OR operations treats is as `false`-y and returns the other operand instead, in this case an empty object `{}`. That object is assigned to `sides[side]`.